# GET from localhost returns code 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the file upload operation option I did with MV.Net, I get the `GET http://localhost:55298/Home/test2.json 404 (Not Found)` error while uploading the file. How can I fix this.

```
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="application/JSON" />
```

```
 var dosyaAdi;
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
        dosyaAdi = e.target.files[0].name;
        $("#file").click(function () {
            if ("#file".length > 1) {
                $('#file').prop('disabled', true);
        }            
    });
        $.getJSON(dosyaAdi, function (data) {
                     $("#btn").click(function () {
                         const trackplayback = L.trackplayback(data, map, {
                             targetOptions: {
                             }
                         });
                         const trackplaybackControl = L.trackplaybackcontrol(trackplayback);
                         trackplaybackControl.addTo(map);
                     })
                 })

    });
```

Comment: have you tried to fetch data from API using Postman?

Comment: no i haven't tried

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:55298/Home/test2.json` - look at the Url - your GET method is hitting the `/Home/test2.json` Url. As a result the system is looking for a physical file called `test2.json`. Not looking for an Action.

What is the name of the Action that you are trying to hit?
If it is a GET method then you can simply test the action from a web browser.

Also you had mentioned that you are trying to upload a file. Unless it is a Ajax request, you should do `Http POST` to upload files instead of `GET`.